# Different keyboard type in the same extended Activity Android (Tab key or "right arrow button" in keyboard)

Tags: android, keyboard, arrow-keys

I have a Login Activity that I extend from a external library.

There is a screenshot of 3 different apps whit the same Android version (8.0) in the same device, but in the last app we can see "arrow to right" in the keyboard (or maybe another keyboard type).

My question in simple: How can I disable this arrow by code?

Ty for your help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its based on the imeOptions of the field.  The check mark usually applies to actionDone.  My guess for the tab would be actionNext, or possibly no value set.  Of course how different keyboards react to different options is up to them.

Comment: This is true, the problem was the `imeOptions` in the password EditText, just add `editText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);` ty for your help !!!